# Cant get the right number of items in listview while working with groups

Tags: listview, count, clone

I have a list that copy itself to another list using clone(),
the problem is that when I'm trying to get the count from the list that I cloned, It grows by 1, but in fact , I added the item to the other list, so it shoudlnt grow.

it only happens when I'm in a group:

```
for each (ListViewItem^ item in chosenList->Items)
    {
         cloneList->Items->Add((ListViewItem^)item->Clone());
        }
```

notice that "chosenList" has groups in it, and item blongs to a group(`item->group!=NULL`).

now when I'm trying to get "chosenlist" group[0] size (`chosenList->Group[0]->Items->count`)
I get double then the size I expact..
How do I fix this?!

I was stuck on this all day so answers would help me so much!!!

thanks! asaf